# Node subscribe error

Tags: ros, callback, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've the error with node I tried these both

```
class DriveControlNode 
{
    public: DriveControlNode( ros::NodeHandle& node ) 
    {
         joy_sub = node.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("/joy",1000,Joystick_callback);
       //joy_sub = node.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("/joy",1000,boost::bind(&DriveControlNode::Joystick_callback,this,_1));         
     }      

    void Joystick_callback(sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& msg)
    {
            // some values
    }   
}
```

errors are as follows
Case 1:

```
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:225:11: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, DriveControlNode, boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Joy_<std::allocator<void> > >&>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Joy_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
```

Case 2:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:9: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, DriveControlNode, boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Joy_<std::allocator<void> > >&>) (DriveControlNode*&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Joy_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
```

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58259/node-subscribe-error/) by [kiranadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/4433/kiranadam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In here was the problem

void Joystick_callback(sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& msg)
{
// some values
}

missed const

void Joystick_callback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& msg)
{
// some values
}

Thanks for the reply

---

Originally posted by [kiranadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/4433/kiranadam/) with karma: 76 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-02-04**:
I have a similar problem and this do not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try it this way:

```
joy_sub = node.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("/joy", 1000, DriveControlNode::Joystick_callback, this);
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kiranadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/4433/kiranadam/) on 2013-03-15**:
void Joystick_callback(sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& msg)
{
// some values
}  here